# Tomcat 9 HTTP/2 Images getting "randomly" corrupted

Tags: tomcat, http2

I have a problem with serving pages with Tomcat 9 via HTTP/2. Images are "randomly" corrupted or not displayed at all. Google Chome complaints about ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR and Tomcat's log is full of following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unicode character [Č] at code point [268] cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range of 0 to 255.
at org.apache.coyote.http2.HPackHuffman.encode(HPackHuffman.java:448)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.HpackEncoder.writeHuffmanEncodableValue(HpackEncoder.java:223)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.HpackEncoder.encode(HpackEncoder.java:185)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.doWriteHeaders(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:579)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.writeHeaders(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:533)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream.writeHeaders(Stream.java:422)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.prepareResponse(StreamProcessor.java:111)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:323)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:211)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:441)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http2OutputBuffer.java:57)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:603)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:653)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:368)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:346)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:140)
at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:132)
at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:124)
at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:230)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
at com.m2000.shop.controllers.DefaultController.image(DefaultController.java:1113)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.m2000.shop.filters.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.m2000.shop.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:24)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at psiprobe.Tomcat90AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat90AgentValve.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.service(StreamProcessor.java:324)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.process(StreamProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamRunnable.run(StreamRunnable.java:35)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`at org.apache.coyote.http2.HPackHuffman.encode(HPackHuffman.java:448)` is the part that encodes HTTP headers. It's complaining that it's being asked to encode a non-ASCII character (`Č`).

The behavior that you are seeing [was introduced by a patch](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/0e7da3dbecf88e90f092f0e6dc9342f4e193357e#diff-88d4caab89e98a9f4bd94a22dee74876) fixing another issue: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60451
That patch has the unfortunate side effect of effectively forbidding non-ASCII characters. Another fix would have been to treat the string as a series of bytes, instead of using `String.charAt` and rejecting values above 255.

Bytes between 128 and 255 in header values are allowed by [RFC 7320 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2), as `obs-text`, and web servers allow them because in practice many headers in the wild use UTF-8 which uses that range. (`Č` is encoded as 0xC4 0x8C)

In order to fix the issue, I would report this issue to the Tomcat project, in the bug tracker above. In the interim, if you are able to identify and remove the headers containing non-ASCII characters you might be able to workaround the issue.

Comment: Related: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66196 and https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66512